# Error al utilizar la instrucción INSERT INTO con un valor de tipo varchar de 8000 caracteres en SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, insert

recientemente estoy utilizando una base de datos de SQL Server, y me he percatado, que al intentar insertar en una tabla que tiene un campo de tipo varchar(8000), al introducirle una cadena de 2000 caracteres, no es capaz de hacerlo devolviendo un error.
Nótese que se que es por este campo, ya que intenté ingresar el registro con otro valor mucho más pequeño, y me dejó.

Si alguien puede llegar a tener una respuesta, o una solución para arreglar esta limitación, estaría muy agradecido.

Muchas gracias de antemano

---

Este es el error que devuelve:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: No puede ser por la limitación que comentas. Tiene que ser por otro motivo. Pon la estructura de la tabla, y el código con el que haces la inserción, y además el error que te muestra.

Comment: O haces algún cálculo adicional antes de la inserción o tienes algún tipo de desencadenador instead of insert o after insert. ¿Puedes pegar el código con el que haces la inserción, y adicionalmente el código del trigger/s que disponga la tabla?

Comment: Para próximas oportunidades, atiende los comentarios y añade la información que te están indicando. Como ves, lo que comentó JaviFer fueron _adivinaciones_ porque no teníamos cómo saber cuál era la definición de la tabla.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Muchas gracias @Javi fer2, efectivamente era por la estructura de la tabla, el campo de varchar(8000) era de tipo UNIQUE, he podido averiguar que solo admite hasta 1700 o 900 bytes como máximo por el índice del constraint.

Muchas gracias por tu ayuda.